# akka http mock (authorization) directive

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mocking, akka, akka-http

I'm trying to write unit testing to an akka-http server (route), but having trouble with the authorization directive. 
I simply want to ignore (mock) the authorization directive.

A minimal version of my code:

```
object App {

    val logger: Logger = Logger[App]

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("my-system")
        implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContextExecutor = system.dispatcher

        val service = new TestRoute()
        val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(service.route, "0.0.0.0", 8080)

        bindingFuture.onComplete {
            case Success(_) => println(s"listening on localhost:8080")
            case Failure(error) => println(s"failed: ${error.getMessage}")
        }
    }


    object TestRoute {

        def authorize: Directive1[JsObject] = extractCredentials.flatMap {
            case Some(OAuth2BearerToken(token)) => verifyToken(token) match {
                case Success(t) =>
                    logger.debug("token verified successfully")
                    provide(t)
                case Failure(t) =>
                    logger.warn(s"token is not valid: ${t.getMessage}")
                    reject(Rejections.validationRejection(t.getMessage))
            }
            case _ =>
                logger.warn("no token present in request")
                reject(AuthorizationFailedRejection)
        }


        def verifyToken(token: String): Try[JsObject] = {
            val source = Source.fromResource("public_production.pem")
            val fileData = try source.mkString finally source.close()
            JwtSprayJson.decodeJson(token, fileData, Seq(JwtAlgorithm.RS256))
        }
    }

    class TestRoute {
        val route: Route =
            TestRoute.authorize { jwtClaims =>
                println(jwtClaims)
                complete("sucess")
            } 
    }
}
```

I want to test the Route in `TestRoute`. So `authorize` is the directive I want to mock. I simply want to control what `authorize` will return, without having to actually getting in the function.

My colleague suggested to wrap the Route in some kind of class that will take the `authorize` method as an argument, such that in the unit-test I can control it very easily. But I'm looking for the mock answer.

I saw some examples with Mockito, but none of them were compatible with my scalatest version, which is `3.1.0`.